# for loop results 0 - php syntax error?

Tags: php, syntax, for-loop

Why does the following php syntax yield 0? note: all the other variables have values assigned.

```
    $p=  $_POST["arate"]/$srate; //A
    $c= $_POST["capacity"];
    $s= 0.0;

    for($i=1;$i<c;$i++){
    $s= (1.0 + $s) * (floatval($i) / $p);
    }
    ?>
    <?php echo $s; ?>
```

Comment: Before the loop, echo your `$p and $c` values and post them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing a `$` at `c` in `for($i=1;$i<c;$i++)` => `for($i=1;$i<$c;$i++)`

and missing `$` at `i` in `(floatval(i) / $p);` => `(floatval($i) / $p);`

Answer (score 2):

The loop is never run, as you compare `$i` with an undefined constant `c`.

If you set `error_reporting(E_ALL)` then you get the following message:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant c - assumed 'c' in ...

Hence, PHP interprets `c` as string `'c'` and any number is bigger then a string (thus, `$i < c` evaluates to false).

Change it to `$i < $c`.

Answer (score 1):

you should change your for loop as well:

`for($i=1;$i<c;$i++){`
should be

```
 for($i=1;$i<$c;$i++){
```

edit: sorry, was to late

Answer (score 0):

`floatval(i)` should be `floatval($i)`, right?